# use the result of function as a new function's parameter, but why exception occurred?

Tags: java, kryo

i wrote a lite RPC framework and use `kryo` serialize object.
but exception occurred when i wrote like this

```
RpcResponse rpcResponse = new RpcResponse(input.readInt(), kryo.readClassAndObject(input), input.readBoolean());
```

so i use another way to init my `RpcResponse` object.

```
int id = input.readInt();
boolean isInvokeSuccess = input.readBoolean();
Object resultOrThrowable = kryo.readClassAndObject(input);

RpcResponse rpcResponse = new RpcResponse(id, resultOrThrowable, isInvokeSuccess);
```

and it works.

so my question is: is there any difference between these two way that i used?

the exception is

```
io.netty.handler.codec.DecoderException: com.esotericsoftware.kryo.KryoException: Unable to find class: abc123123
at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:459)
at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:265)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1434)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:965)
at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:163)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:647)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:582)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:499)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:461)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:884)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.esotericsoftware.kryo.KryoException: Unable to find class: abc123123
at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.util.DefaultClassResolver.readName(DefaultClassResolver.java:156)
at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.util.DefaultClassResolver.readClass(DefaultClassResolver.java:133)
at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readClass(Kryo.java:670)
at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readClassAndObject(Kryo.java:781)
at org.develcarl.rpc.serializer.RpcResponseSerializer.read(RpcResponseSerializer.java:30)
at org.develcarl.rpc.serializer.RpcResponseSerializer.read(RpcResponseSerializer.java:14)
at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readClassAndObject(Kryo.java:790)
at org.develcarl.rpc.serializer.KryoSerializer.deserialize(KryoSerializer.java:56)
at org.develcarl.rpc.netty.NettyKryoDecoder.decode(NettyKryoDecoder.java:28)
at io.netty.handler.codec.LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder.decode(LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder.java:343)
at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:489)
at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:428)
... 16 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: abc123123
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.util.DefaultClassResolver.readName(DefaultClassResolver.java:154)
... 27 more
```

Comment: I believe there is no difference between the two calls, but providing the stacktrace here might be helpful in diagnosing where things went wrong. Please provide the stacktrace as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The second one works. The order of operations **matters**, you have `int`, `boolean`, `Object`. In your first example you read `int`, `Object`, `boolean`. You could do,

```
int id = input.readInt();
boolean isInvokeSuccess = input.readBoolean();
RpcResponse rpcResponse = new RpcResponse(id, 
        kryo.readClassAndObject(input), isInvokeSuccess);
```

Regardless, you have to read the fields in the order they're written.

Comment: Oh my... i find my function `write` and the write order is what you said. Really thank you!